# Searching certain terms in a question page finds invisible text

Tags: bug

In any question page, searching the current page for the terms

- `up vote`
- `down vote`
- `accepted`
- `favorite`

will find the corresponding up/downvote buttons, the checkmark of an accepted answer (if there is one) and the favorite button. I believe this is not desirable since the search is supposed to find visible text only.

This happens at least on Firefox 21.0 and Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: So, essentially you are saying your don't want the browser search to behave this way?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, isn't it the browser itself that is at fault? This doesn't seem like an SO/SE bug to me.

Comment: Currently, the text is being hidden using `text-indent: -9999em`, which is a bit of a hack. Can't really blame the browser for not being able to deal with that. I'm assuming that if the text were in an element hidden with `display: none` it might behave differently, but it's likely more trouble than it's worth to change it.

Comment: For the record, I just tried it in Chrome 27 and the search function finds the hidden "up vote" text, but not the text in my comment when I added `display: none` to it.

Comment: @hammar That's interesting; I haven't done this in a while, but I've noticed differing behavior on browser's search for 'hidden' text. For instance: `bl<span style="display:none;">ERG</span>ah` as an example; one browser's text search found "blah", another wouldn't.